# save the value of checked box into database

Tags: php, html, mysql, codeigniter

this is my php code. i want to save the value of checked box into database.

```
$checkbox = "";
if(!empty($_POST)) { 
for (!$i=0; $i<sizeof($checkbox);$i++) {
$query="INSERT INTO qe_qcc (checkbox) VALUES ('".$checkbox[$i]."')";
mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
}
```

this is my html code

```
<tr>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="check1[]" value="Enhance Productivity" />Enhance      Productivity</td>
<td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" name="check1[]" value="Enhance Quality"   />Enhance Quality</td>
<td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" name="check1[]" value="Save Time" />Save   Time</td>
<td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" name="check1[]" value="Save Materials" />Save Materials</td>
<td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" name="check1[]" value="Save Stock" />Save Stock</td>
<td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" name="check1[]" value="Increase Safety" />Increase Safety</td>
<td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" name="check1[]" value="Financial Saving" />Financial Saving</td>
<td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" name="check1[]" value="Customer Friendly" />Customer Friendly</td>
<td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <br /><br /><input type="checkbox" name="check1[]" value="Others" />Others</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: `!$i=0`? `sizeof("")`? What is all this?

Comment: Why you don't use codeigniter Active record

Comment: imran, can u explain it to me? because im not too expert with codeigniter.

Comment: Kiren Siva, my error is there is no data saved in my database eventhough i've checked the value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all do not use `mysql_` , it is deprecated.. (in CI .. u can easily change it)

Second if you are using codeigniter then use active records

Then Third...

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST))
{
     foreach($_POST['check1'] as $rescheck)
     {
         $this->db->insert('qe_qcc', $rescheck); 
     }
 }
 ?>
```

OR better use

```
  <?php  $data = array();
 if(isset($_POST))
{
     foreach($_POST['check1'] as $rescheck)
     {
         $data[] = $rescheck
     }
 }
  $this->db->insert_batch('mytable', $data);
 ?>
```

To store all checkbox value in one column:

> $check_value = implode(',',$_POST['check1']);

Comment: thanks DS9. but what should i do if i want to save multiple value of checkbox into one column of database?

Comment: then implode array and store it as comma seperated value.check updated answer.

Comment: $effects="";
    $effects=$_POST['effects'];
    for ($i=0; $i<count($effects);$i++){
    $query="INSERT INTO qe_qcc (effects) VALUES ('".$effects[$i]."')"; }
    mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
    $effects_value = implode(',',$_POST['effects']); 
     
     {

Comment: why i still cann't save multiple value of checked box in one column?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
   $checkbox=$_POST['check1'];
        for ($i=0; $i<count($checkbox);$i++) {
         $query="INSERT INTO qe_qcc (checkbox) VALUES ('".$checkbox[$i]."')";
           mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

        }
```

Comment: i want to save multiple value of checked box in the same column.what should i do?

Comment: $check = $_POST['check1'];
$check = implode(',',$check);
$query="INSERT INTO qe_qcc (checkbox) VALUES ('".$check."')";

Answer (score 0):

You can use implode

```
$checkbox=implode(',', $_POST['check1']);
$query="INSERT INTO qe_qcc (checkbox) VALUES ('".$checkbox."')";
mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 0):

in HTML

```
<form name ="check" action="" method="POST">
<tr>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="check1[]" value="Enhance Productivity" />Enhance      Productivity</td>
<td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" name="check1[]" value="Enhance Quality"   />Enhance Quality</td>
<td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" name="check1[]" value="Save Time" />Save   Time</td>
<td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" name="check1[]" value="Save Materials" />Save Materials</td>
<td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" name="check1[]" value="Save Stock" />Save Stock</td>
<td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" name="check1[]" value="Increase Safety" />Increase Safety</td>
<td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" name="check1[]" value="Financial Saving" />Financial Saving</td>
<td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" name="check1[]" value="Customer Friendly" />Customer Friendly</td>
<td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <br /><br /><input type="checkbox" name="check1[]" value="Others" />Others</td>
 </tr>
<input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

in php

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['check1'])){
$check = $_POST['check1'];
foreach($check as $checked) {
      $query="INSERT INTO qe_qcc (checkbox) VALUES ('".$checked."')";
      mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

    }
   }
 ?>
```